# Shortest_Path Interpretation of Edge Weight

Tags: networkx

If I calculate the length of the shortest path using `networkx` as:

```
path_length = nx.shortest_path_length(G, source = origin, target = destination, weight = 'distance')
```

How does `networkx` know to interpret the edge attribute as a distance or a weight?

[The documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html?highlight=shortest_path#networkx-algorithms-shortest-paths-generic-shortest-path) says either is acceptable but doesn't specify how the attribute will be interpreted.

In the case of a weight, I would expect high values to be preferred. The shortest path traveling through the edges of the highest weights.

In the case of a distance, I would expect lower values to be preferred, to minimize total distance.

Am I missing something conceptually?

The results I've gotten are consistent with my expectations for distances but it's uncomfortable that I can't find anything in the docs that clarifies this.

Comment: Whether it is distance or weight the objective is minimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> weight (None or string, optional (default = None)) – If None, every
>   edge has weight/distance/cost 1. If a string, use this edge attribute
>   as the edge weight. Any edge attribute not present defaults to 1.

So Whether it is a distance or weight the objective is minimization. Usually words like *profit/utility* refer to maximization, while *weight/distance/cost* to minimization, some others like *fitness* may be used in both cases.

Comment: I've read that sentence like 100 times and just can't get confident that weight is minimization. I agree _usually_ but it would be nice to know for sure. Thanks for the input at least.